# ical update not working in outlook

Tags: java, outlook, icalendar, rfc5545

I created an outlook meeting and I am trying to update the same meeting using my Java application by making use of the ical's `UID` parameter. However, the corresponding meeting is not getting updated but a new event is getting created.

Below is the Outlook generated Event Details

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:India Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN="test";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:test@xyz.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20141204T134739Z
DESCRIPTION:sdsd\n
DTEND;TZID="India Standard Time":20141204T200000
DTSTAMP:20141204T134715Z
DTSTART;TZID="India Standard Time":20141204T194500
LAST-MODIFIED:20141204T134739Z
LOCATION:none
ORGANIZER;CN="User, Dummy":mailto:dummy.user@xyz.com
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-in:att
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000009039D3E9F60FD001000000000000000
    0100000009DB93D567DD8004997175904B7FA6AE1
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E
    N">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server ve
    rsion 14.02.5004.000">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<!-- Converted f
    rom text/rtf format -->\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calib
    ri">sdsd</FONT></SPAN><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SPAN></P>\n\n</BODY>\n</HTML>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-APPTSEQTIME:20141204T134715Z
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

And below is the `iCal` object which I am using to modify the `DTSTART` and `DTEND`. I also changed the `SEQUENCE` from 0 to 1

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:India Standard Time
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:16010101T000000
TZOFFSETFROM:+0530
TZOFFSETTO:+0530
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN="test";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:test@xyz.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20141204T134739Z
DESCRIPTION:sdsd\n
DTEND;TZID="India Standard Time":20141204T210000
DTSTAMP:20141204T134715Z
DTSTART;TZID="India Standard Time":20141204T204500
LAST-MODIFIED:20141204T134739Z
LOCATION:none
ORGANIZER;CN="User, Dummy":mailto:dummy.user@xyz.com
PRIORITY:5
SEQUENCE:1
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-in:att
TRANSP:OPAQUE
UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E008000000009039D3E9F60FD001000000000000000
    0100000009DB93D567DD8004997175904B7FA6AE1
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E
    N">\n<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server ve
    rsion 14.02.5004.000">\n<TITLE></TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<!-- Converted f
    rom text/rtf format -->\n\n<P DIR=LTR><SPAN LANG="en-us"><FONT FACE="Calib
    ri">sdsd</FONT></SPAN><SPAN LANG="en-us"></SPAN></P>\n\n</BODY>\n</HTML>
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-APPTSEQTIME:20141204T134715Z
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check your UID value: It looks like the original event is using a HTAB to do the line folding of the UID value. It is well possible that somewhere in your code path, this HTAB gets translated into a serie of simple spaces, hence totally changing the value itself.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-2.1 about icalendar line folding.